# vagrant server instance closed automatically on starting jboss domain

Tags: macos, jboss

I am new to vagrant. I am trying to setup a test environment with jboss. So I have setup a fedora vagrant and installed jboss in it.

Post installation it worked in standalone mode and the console came up. But when I tried the same in domain mode, it starts and the vagrant server closes on its on.

Here is the **nohup.out** log.

```
[0m=========================================================================

  JBoss Bootstrap Environment

  JBOSS_HOME: /home/vagrant/EAP-7.4.0

  JAVA: java

  JAVA_OPTS: -server -Xms64m -Xmx512m -XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=256m -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Djboss.modules.system.pkgs=org.jboss.byteman -Djava.awt.headless=true  --add-exports=java.base/sun.nio.ch=ALL-UNNAMED --add-exports=jdk.unsupported/sun.misc=ALL-UNNAMED --add-exports=jdk.unsupported/sun.reflect=ALL-UNNAMED

=========================================================================

[0m12:17:04,962 INFO  [org.jboss.modules] (main) JBoss Modules version 1.11.0.Final-redhat-00001
[0m[0m12:17:05,982 INFO  [org.jboss.threads] (main) JBoss Threads version 2.4.0.Final-redhat-00001
[0m[0m12:17:05,990 INFO  [org.jboss.as.process.Host Controller.status] (main) WFLYPC0018: Starting process 'Host Controller'
[0m[Host Controller] [0m12:17:06,756 INFO  [org.jboss.modules] (main) JBoss Modules version 1.11.0.Final-redhat-00001[0m
[Host Controller] [0m[0m12:17:07,174 INFO  [org.jboss.msc] (main) JBoss MSC version 1.4.12.Final-redhat-00001[0m
[Host Controller] [0m[0m12:17:07,177 INFO  [org.jboss.threads] (main) JBoss Threads version 2.4.0.Final-redhat-00001[0m
[Host Controller] [0m[0m12:17:07,261 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (MSC service thread 1-1) WFLYSRV0049: JBoss EAP 7.4.0.GA (WildFly Core 15.0.2.Final-redhat-00001) starting[0m
[Host Controller] [0m[0m12:17:07,908 INFO  [org.wildfly.security] (Host Controller Service Threads - 4) ELY00001: WildFly Elytron version 1.15.3.Final-redhat-00001[0m
[Host Controller] [0m[0m12:17:08,074 INFO  [org.jboss.as.controller.management-deprecated] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYCTL0028: Attribute 'security-realm' in the resource at address '/host=master/core-service=management/management-interface=http-interface' is deprecated, and may be removed in a future version. See the attribute description in the output of the read-resource-description operation to learn more about the deprecation.[0m
[Host Controller] [0m[0m12:17:08,160 INFO  [org.jboss.as.host.controller] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYHC0003: Creating http management service using network interface (management) port (9990) securePort (-1)[0m
[Host Controller] [0m[0m12:17:08,179 INFO  [org.xnio] (MSC service thread 1-3) XNIO version 3.8.4.Final-redhat-00001[0m
[Host Controller] [0m[0m12:17:08,181 INFO  [org.xnio.nio] (MSC service thread 1-3) XNIO NIO Implementation Version 3.8.4.Final-redhat-00001[0m
[Host Controller] [0m[0m12:17:08,222 INFO  [org.jboss.remoting] (MSC service thread 1-1) JBoss Remoting version 5.0.20.SP1-redhat-00001[0m
[Host Controller] [0m[0m12:17:08,347 INFO  [org.jboss.as.patching] (MSC service thread 1-2) WFLYPAT0050: JBoss EAP cumulative patch ID is: base, one-off patches include: none[0m
[Host Controller] [0m[33m12:17:08,356 WARN  [org.jboss.as.domain.management.security] (MSC service thread 1-1) WFLYDM0111: Keystore /home/vagrant/EAP-7.4.0/domain/configuration/application.keystore not found, it will be auto generated on first use with a self signed certificate for host localhost[0m
[Host Controller] [33m[0m[0m12:17:10,680 INFO  [org.jboss.as.controller.management-deprecated] (Host Controller Service Threads - 16) WFLYCTL0033: Extension 'security' is deprecated and may not be supported in future versions[0m
[Host Controller] [0m[0m12:17:11,316 INFO  [org.jboss.as.controller.management-deprecated] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYCTL0028: Attribute 'security-realm' in the resource at address '/profile=default/subsystem=undertow/server=default-server/https-listener=https' is deprecated, and may be removed in a future version. See the attribute description in the output of the read-resource-description operation to learn more about the deprecation.[0m
[Host Controller] [0m[0m12:17:11,335 INFO  [org.jboss.as.controller.management-deprecated] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYCTL0028: Attribute 'security-realm' in the resource at address '/profile=ha/subsystem=undertow/server=default-server/https-listener=https' is deprecated, and may be removed in a future version. See the attribute description in the output of the read-resource-description operation to learn more about the deprecation.[0m
[Host Controller] [0m[0m12:17:11,354 INFO  [org.jboss.as.controller.management-deprecated] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYCTL0028: Attribute 'security-realm' in the resource at address '/profile=full/subsystem=undertow/server=default-server/https-listener=https' is deprecated, and may be removed in a future version. See the attribute description in the output of the read-resource-description operation to learn more about the deprecation.[0m
[Host Controller] [0m[0m12:17:11,367 INFO  [org.jboss.as.controller.management-deprecated] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYCTL0028: Attribute 'security-realm' in the resource at address '/profile=full-ha/subsystem=undertow/server=default-server/https-listener=https' is deprecated, and may be removed in a future version. See the attribute description in the output of the read-resource-description operation to learn more about the deprecation.[0m
[Host Controller] [0m[0m12:17:11,503 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYSRV0062: Http management interface listening on http://192.168.56.22:9990/management and https://192.168.56.22:-1/management[0m
[Host Controller] [0m[0m12:17:11,504 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYSRV0053: Admin console listening on http://192.168.56.22:9990 and https://192.168.56.22:-1[0m
[Host Controller] [0m[0m12:17:11,549 INFO  [org.jboss.as.host.controller] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYHC0023: Starting server server-one[0m
[0m12:17:11,605 INFO  [org.jboss.as.process.Server:server-one.status] (ProcessController-threads - 3) WFLYPC0018: Starting process 'Server:server-one'
[0m[Host Controller] [0m[0m12:17:13,623 INFO  [org.jboss.as.host.controller] (management task-2) WFLYHC0021: Server [Server:server-one] connected using connection [Channel ID 778505ec (inbound) of Remoting connection 4a8156a5 to app01/192.168.56.22:60686 of endpoint "master:MANAGEMENT" <5b6d9cbc>][0m
[Host Controller] [0m[0m12:17:13,720 INFO  [org.jboss.as.host.controller] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYHC0023: Starting server server-two[0m
[Host Controller] [0m[0m12:17:13,725 INFO  [org.jboss.as.host.controller] (server-registration-threads - 1) WFLYHC0020: Registering server server-one[0m
[0m12:17:31,831 INFO  [org.jboss.as.process.Server:server-two.status] (ProcessController-threads - 3) WFLYPC0018: Starting process 'Server:server-two'
[0m[Server:server-one] WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred
[Server:server-one] WARNING: Illegal reflective access by org.wildfly.extension.elytron.SSLDefinitions (jar:file:/home/vagrant/EAP-7.4.0/modules/system/layers/base/org/wildfly/extension/elytron/main/wildfly-elytron-integration-15.0.2.Final-redhat-00001.jar!/) to method com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.Provider.isFIPS()
[Server:server-one] WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of org.wildfly.extension.elytron.SSLDefinitions
[Server:server-one] WARNING: Use --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal reflective access operations
[Server:server-one] WARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future release
[Host Controller] [0m[0m12:17:51,936 INFO  [org.jboss.as.host.controller] (management task-2) WFLYHC0021: Server [Server:server-two] connected using connection [Channel ID 2d5e7b07 (inbound) of Remoting connection 04c217a2 to app01/192.168.56.22:60688 of endpoint "master:MANAGEMENT" <5b6d9cbc>][0m
[Host Controller] [0m[0m12:17:52,009 INFO  [org.jboss.as.host.controller] (server-registration-threads - 1) WFLYHC0020: Registering server server-two[0m
[Host Controller] [0m[0m12:17:52,083 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYSRV0025: JBoss EAP 7.4.0.GA (WildFly Core 15.0.2.Final-redhat-00001) (Host Controller) started in 46056ms - Started 80 of 82 services (23 services are lazy, passive or on-demand)[0m
```

This is what is happening on completion of starting the service.

```
[Host Controller] 12:17:52,083 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYSRV0025: JBoss EAP 7.4.0.GA (WildFly Core 15.0.2.Final-redhat-00001) (Host Controller) started in 46056ms - Started 80 of 82 services (23 services are lazy, passive or on-demand)
Connection to 127.0.0.1 closed by remote host.
```

Please let me know what do I need to check for this.